# SVN post-commit hook

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I want to make post-commit hook that copy and commits all files to directory named "2" when I commit the directory named "1".

I use post-commit hook in server-side.
my batch file is following:

```
svn update D:\test\1\ --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MyUserName --password "mypassword"
svn update D:\test\2\ --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MyUserName --password "mypassword"

svn add "D:\test\1\*" --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MyUserName --password "mypassword"

del /Q /S "D:\test\2\*.*"
xcopy /y "D:\test\1\" "D:\test\2\" /E /I

D:
cd D:\test\2\*
svn add * --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MyUserName --password "mypassword"
svn remove * --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MyUserName --password "mypassword"
svn commit --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username MyUserName --password "mypassword" -m "[%DATE%] Data Synchronize"
```

that is my batch.
and when I commit something
then, errors pop up.
that is my errors.

```
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'url/svn/test'  
Error: svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted  
Error: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'url/svn/test'  
Error: svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\1\aef.txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\1\aiaiaiai.txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\1\asd (2).txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\1\df.txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\1\hooking.....txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned  
Error: svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\2\aef.txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\2\aiaiaiai.txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\2\asd (2).txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\2\df.txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: warning: W150002: 'D:\test\2\hooking.....txt' is already under version control  
Error: svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned  
Error: svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation  
Error: svn: E170013: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'url/svn/test/2'  
Error: svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

svn client (when committing something) and svn server are different machines.

how can I solve it?

Do I need other tools?

Comment: The hook script is running on your server. As you correctly assume, you cannot access files on your client from your server (unless you're sharing them, but that's an unrelated topic). What's the problem you're trying to solve? Why copy those files? Why have two repos with the same content?